# C language, how find the length of a word in a 2d array?

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array, string-length

I am trying to make a condition for a for loop where i have to say `(c<wordlength)` but im not sure how to find the length of the word.

so lets say i have an arrary called...

```
char shopping[10][10]={"BAGELS","HAM","EGGS"};
```

what is the right syntax to find that shopping[0] has 6 letters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The right syntax is

```
strlen(shopping[0])
```

This returns a value of type `size_t` that does not include the NUL terminator.

See [`man strlen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen) for details.

If you are using `strlen(unchanging_string)` as the terminal condition of a loop, it is prudent to call it once before the loop instead of calling it on every iteration.

An alternative way to loop over the characters of `shopping[0]` is as follows:

```
char *s = shopping[0];
while (*s) {
  /* (*s) is the current character */
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
size_t len = strlen(shopping[0]);
```

Note, though, that you should not write:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(shopping[0]); i++)
```

This can lead to bad performance on long strings.  Use:

```
size_t len = strlen(shopping[0]);
for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
```

Comment: would it not be better to avoid the for loop altogether? `strlen() + 1` should give the length right?

Comment: @Koushik: it depends on the larger context; what are you really trying to do.  You can make a case for `for (size_t i = 0; shopping[0][i] != '\0'; i++)` as well as the solutions using `strlen()`.  The trailing question was 'how to find that the string contains 6 characters', and my first answer is precisely the way to do that.  The starting question mentioned a `for` loop; I hypothesized some possible `for` loop constructs and recommended calling `strlen()` once rather than N times.  Without more code in the question, it is not easy to help more.

Answer (score 2):

Actually `shopping[0]`  has 7 chars one you forgot `\0` char  that is for string termination. Although `strlen()` give you length of string, that number of char before `\0`.

```
strlen(shopping[0])
```

But Total char are `strlen(shopping[0]) + 1` = 7

In memory your `shopping[0]` is something like:

```
+----+----+----+---+---+----+----+----+---+---+ 
| 'B'| 'A' |'G'|'E'|'L'| 'S'|'\0'| 0  | 0 |   |
+----+----+----+---+---+----+----+----+---+---+
                              ^ `\0` also a char in shopping[0]
```

**Edit**:

As I read your question again you says 6 **letters** So `strlen(shopping[0]
)` is your answer give you 6.

Because you *wants a loop* to find number of letters (char in my answer non '\0') then calling `strlen()` is useless. I would like that you should take benefit of null termination string in C:

```
int num=0;
for(num = 0; shopping[0][num]!='\0'; num++);
printf("\n  number of letters are %d\n",num);
```

<sub>I think other answers are **not** good, they are using strlen() unnecessary. If I am  missing something, Please let me know</sub>

Comment: You're in danger of redefining a string.  The C standard says (§7.1.1 Definitions): 'A _string_ is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null
character.  [...] The _length of a string_ is the number of bytes preceding the null character.'  Emphasis as in ISO/IEC 9899:2011.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't think My answer is wrong strings are null `\0` terminated in C. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan `shopping[0][num] = '\0'` is wrong . it should be equality not assignment

Comment: @JonathanLeffler in-effect I don't like you solution because you unnecessary calls  `strlen()` before loop. I believe my loop is better then you to count number of chars. Yes: I read many of your answers those very good. But Suggest me Should I remove my answer? Please help me instead to improve my answer.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan shopping[0][num] = '\0' is assigning null to it. by your code your **redefinin** the string to be all `NULL`. should be `!=`.

Comment: the first solution is sufficiently good. why the second solution? is it just alternate way that your showing?

Comment: @Koushik OP wants to do using loop as I understands. And suggesting strlen() is not correct way if we want to count number of chars in a string.

Comment: oh totally forgot that.:-). and the `strlen() + 1` is not necessary i guess(he just wants the number of printable characters i guess).

Comment: @Koushik No Koushik My first answer is `strlen(shopping[0])` and second one is using loop the code I given. I don't know why Jonathan Leffler down voted me And not replying back. Sad :(  I just stated that `shopping[0] has 7 chars ` but doesn't says string contain `7` chars.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: I didn't down vote you.  I made a comment, that's all.  And my comment says you need to be careful, not that you're actually wrong.  There are 7 characters in the string; the length of the string, though, is 6.  There's an argument that 10 characters are allocated for the storage.  You don't like my solution: OK, that's your privilege.  As I've commented to Koushik, a lot depends on what else is going on in the code — as usual, there's more than one way to do it (TMTOWTDI — the motto of Perl).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks lots to respond me back Jonathan. I really appropriate and now happy. I didn't like you answer because of we can do without `strlen()`... But I read many of your posts And You might not remember but somewhere I commented to you also. Anyways I am happy to have an interaction with you Please Apologize me if I said something wrong.

Comment: You should benchmark your `for` loop against `strlen()` under maximal optimization for speed.  My money would be on `strlen()` being faster than your loop, by quite a margin, especially on longer strings.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler :) :)  but One day I will post a code that you would like. And soon

Answer (score 1):

You can write the code using a `for` loop to find the size of each element in the shopping array:

```
for(i =0;i<10;i++)
{
    j=0;
    while(shopping[i][j])
    {
        j++;
    }
}
```

where `j` will return the size of each shopping array element.

Comment: Would it be better to use nested `for` loops?  The inner might be: `for (j = 0; shopping[i][j] != '\0'; j++)`.  That gets all the controls on one line (and you drop the `!= '\0'` if you want to, though I prefer the explicit comparison).